# Can't execute a paragraph's onLoad event in react? (or: how to get an attribute when the p element is loaded and send it to Firebase?)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, attributes, onload, paragraph

I am setting up a **React.js** app where each component is a different chapter of an article. I want to listen to the load event of the chapter's paragraph element and submit its date to **Google Firebase realtime database**, so I need to get each chapter's name, which I thought would be better with an attribute. My code does work with an `onClick` event, but not with an `onLoad`:

```js
// Epilogue.jsx

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {getName} from './clicksCounters';

class Epilogue extends Component {
    render () {
            return <p part='epilogue' onLoad={getName}> // the attribute i am trying to get is "part".
        i am the epilogue chapter!
    </p>
    }


}

export default Epilogue;


// clicksCounters.jsx

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

function getName(e) {
    let refTitle = e.currentTarget.part; //the attribute is taken to here.
    submitWords();
    function submitWords(){
        const submittedWords = firebase.database().ref('clicks/chapter/' + refTitle); //this is where i want it, as a subdirectory.
    saveWords();
    function saveWords() {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;
        const newMessageRef = submittedWords.push();
        newMessageRef.set({
            Date: today + ' ; ' + Date()
        });
    }   
    }
}

export {getName};
```

When i use `()` ( for example: `onLoad={getName()}` ), I am getting this error: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined*.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this?

THANKS MUCH! ♥

Comment: Why not using `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: Hi, @Amir-Mousavi. That's because I wanted to get the attribute from the paragraph that is unloaded... I thought of using a variable instead, and declare it inside ``componentDidMount``, but kept getting "undefined" as the database path (in the Firebase console).

Comment: 1. The `part` is not a correct prop for `p` tag you can have `id`, `className`, `onClick`,...
2. if you are using React stick to React lifecycle cause `onLoad` is not working on `p` tag
3. it is better to upload the `componentDidMount` approach where you get `undefined` error